# find and replace with regular expression in visual studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm new to `regx` and in visual studio 2010 I want to find

```
 </local>
 <local>
 <some words>
 </local>
```

and replace it with

```
 </local>
```

I can find first line by

```
/[local]+[>][\n]
```

but I don't know what should I do to find whole expression.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want to remove anything after `</local>`

So, just do `(?s)(?<=</local>).*?</localizedCaptions>`
and replace with an empty string. `(?s)` is SingleLine modifier.

If `(?s)` isn't working, then just do `(?<=</local>)[\s\S]*?</localizedCaptions>`

Comment: (?s)(?<=</local>).*?</localizedCaptions>  doesn't find </local>
 <local>
 <some words>
 </local>